# How do C++ developers capture programmatic errors in release builds?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ application that crashes with segfault with some unknown customer data. Customer refuses to share his input data. Is it possible to figure out where did error happen?

When Java application crashes on end-user side it usually produces a stack trace that can help developer to figure out where is the error in program and what program invariants where broken.

But what should C++ developer do in this case? Should I recompile application with some compiler option so it provides some diagnostics when error happens?

Comment: It is operating system and compiler specific. On Linux, your customer might setup his system to dump a [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) and send that to you; and you might recompile your code with debug [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) information (by recompiling your code with `g++ -g` ...)

Comment: You might use static analyzers (perhaps as simple as [clang-analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/)...) on your code. You certainly should enable all warnings when compiling (so `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)

Comment: Your question is really too broad. You don't tell anything about your application? Have you used [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on it?

Comment: You can add some logs in your program where do you expect that problems can occur. You can then tell the user to send you the log file so you can have an idea of what happened.

Comment: It is very operation-system specific. Unix has coredumps, Windows has minidumps, but overall the question is way too broad.

Comment: *Is it possible to figure out where did error happen?* -- I'll be the mildly harsh one here.  You need to be ready to debug your application when errors happen with release builds.  This is one of the prerequisites of releasing software to customers.  If you were not ready and just asking on stack overflow about whether it is possible to debug release builds, that looks poorly on the developers and/or management.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie Good decisions come from experience, and experience comes from bad decisions.  You were a newbie once as well.

Comment: Well, even as a newbie, I would never consider delivering software to the public, knowing full well I may not be able to diagnose the problem.  I can understand first doing the research on this topic on debugging release builds, then release the software.  But the other way around where you release the software as if nothing can go wrong, and then sit there dumbfounded when a problem arises, I consider that unacceptable.  Of course IMO.

Comment: When one think the question is too broad, does it means one cannot imagine a sufficiently abstract answer such that this answer still provides information while being as broad as the question?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If the customer does not want to provide the input data, I will probably refuse to provide the core dump.

Comment: @Oliv -- That is a fair point.  If the customer's data contains sensitive or confidential info, then it is possible that the core dump also contains that info in some string form.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I did use google sanitizers, and they did not capture any issues. Should I use valgrind instead?

Comment: If your customer doesn't want to share the inputs that can reproduce the crash, then ask them to provide the core dump. If they refuse that as well due to sensitive data, then ask them if they would be willing to try to reproduce it with inputs that aren't sensitive data.  If they aren't willing to do that, then well it's hard for you to help them isn't it?  "Help me help you."  You should incorporate static analysis into your build process, build with maximum warning levels enabled, and try your best to write good unit tests to exercise your logic (CppUnit, GTest, GMock, etc.)

Comment: Ok, from what I've learned from comments is that the answer is core dump /minidump. In my case customer does not know what it is and will likely share it if I ask, and I have no intention to extract user data from it.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie In my life this "unacceptable" happens all the time, you never know what can go wrong.

Comment: @random • my product uses extensive logging, and when it has an unexpected crash (oh noes!) we try to also dump a backtrace.  The customer has to opt-in send us their logs.  The logs are sent the next time the application is launched.

Comment: Sometimes we don't ;) Sometimes we guess. In both cases a lot of drinking is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the input data required to recreate the problem (for whatever reason...including difficult customers) and you don't have core/minidumps, there is not much you can do.  I've been in many situations such as this. My recourse was to recreate what I thought was the execution path based on interviewing the customer and then just do a meticulous code review to find possibilities of error conditions.  I would test every candidate condition and eventually find the problem.  This is painful, time consuming, and the main prerequisite is that you are able to read code nearly like you're reading your native language.

**Begin Story Time**

I worked somewhere that had a crash bug randomly manifest in a multi-tenant system.  No amount of logging, core dumps, etc. would help us find it.  Finally I reviewed the code (line. by. line. for multiple thousands of lines) and noticed that the developer was constructing a std::string instance from a char* sequence passed to the ctor.  It was DEEP down in the parts of the code that hardly ever changed, so correlating the issue to recent changes was just a set of false leads.  I asked the developer, "Are all your char arrays null terminated?"  Answer: "No."  Me: "Well we are then randomly reading memory until it finds a null, and apparently sometimes the heap has a lot of contiguous non-zero memory."  Handling the char array bounds differently resulted in fixing the problem.

**End Story Time**

While you can't find a single way to find all bugs, there is a defensive design you can apply that is quite simple.  Most people put it in the code once they get burned by this type of situation.  The approach is to add support for different levels of logging verbosity and essentially instrument your code with log outputs that don't execute unless the code is set to use the correct level of verbosity. Turning the verbosity level up until the bug is recreated gives you at least some idea of where it is happening.  Often customers will not have a problem sharing redacted log data (assuming there is sensitive data in the logs).  Load the logs in Splunk or something similar (if the customer doesn't already aggregate their logs in an analysis tool) and you'll have an easier time reviewing the data.

Unfortunately with C++ you don't get nice stack traces and post-mortem data for free (in general).  You have to add these post-mortem troubleshooting capabilities into your design up front.  Most of the design gets driven from the expected deployment environment and user personas of your code, so add "difficult customer" as a persona and start coding. :)

Comment: Can confirm this is accurate. Needs more reference to alcohol and swearing though... ;)